# Mysql Changing secure_file_priv in terminal MAC OS

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, workbench

new stackflow user here.

Im also new with SQL and learning to use it with MAC OS and MySQL Workbench 8.0.

My problem is that I cant change secure_file_priv value. Its NULL and stays NULL no matter what.

I have tried to use tips and tricks found from stackoverflow but the value stays the same whatever code I try to put in terminal.

Basically if I start with **/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p** in terminal. Is this wrong start?

Because after typing that in, all I have managed to do in terminal is 'show variables;'.
Any other code I've found from internet (regarding this problem) doesn't return anything.

Idea behind everything is to use LOAD DATA INFILE function in MySQL Workbench. But error 1290 denies that. Or LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE which returns error code 3948

Thanks in advance.